# Smoothness of reparameterization

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, curves, chain-rule

Suppose we have a parametric curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$, i.e. $\phi: [a, b] \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $\phi(s) = (\phi_1(s), \phi_2(s))$ for $s \in [a, b]$. Suppose there is a different parameterization of the curve, $\psi: [c, d] \in \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $\psi(t) = (\psi_1(t), \psi_2(t))$ for $t \in [c, d]$. If $\psi$ and $\phi$ are locally invertible, we define a reparameterization as $f: [a, b] \to [c, d]$, $f(s) = (\psi^{-1} \circ \phi)(s)$.

My question is whether, if we know that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth, we can conclude that $f$ is also smooth. My professor said that we can't use the chain rule, because although we map from an open set in $[a, b]$, the part of the curve which we then map back to a part of $[c, d]$ is not itself an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. He then provided a simple argument by which we can extend the functions in question to map from open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to other open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, allowing for use of the multivariable chain rule.

1. I would appreciate if someone could provide a precise statement of the multivariable chain rule which states that the images should be open sets. I can't find this anywhere.
2. Could someone provide an intuitive explanation, perhaps with a counterexample in an analogous situation where this doesn't hold, of why we can't conclude that the inverse of the smooth function $\psi$ is itself smooth?

Comment: Hint: Consider the maps $\phi: t\mapsto t^3$ and $\psi: t\mapsto t^5$ from the unit interval to itself. Are they smooth? Is the composition $\psi^{-1}\circ \phi$ smooth?

Comment: @MoisheKohan no, but they are smooth when restricted to $(0, 1]$. So is the condition related to the chain rule and open sets to ensure that the behaviour at the endpoints is not "qualitatively" different?

Comment: I meant the unit interval $[-0.5, 0.5]$, so it has nothing to do with the end-points. I suggest, you check with your instructor what a "parameterization" means in the context of your class. Does it include the requirement of nowhere vanishing derivative? Then the claim indeed holds. But the non-vanishing derivative implies that both maps are locally invertible, so it's unclear to me what your instructor actually meant. It's possible that you copied their lecture incorrectly.